# Clustered Index change on SQL Azure making INSERT very slow on a big table of sensor data (from ~30ms to 2000ms)

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database

I´m tryng to improve the performance of a large table on my Multi-Tenant SaaS System to make the reports more faster. 
When i added an column on clustered index the time to make an insert operation on the system increased from ~30ms to 1500~2500ms!! 
What is the best clustered index option and Non-clustered Index to apply to this table under this situations:

- Database: SQL Azure
- I only perform INSERT and SELECT on this table, data never is updated (UPDATE)
- High load of concurrent INSERTS (Different Workers and threads consuming data from a Queue)
- 100.000 rows/day (growing)
- Actually 6 milions rows (growing)
- Each tenant only read data for his ID
- 1 Tenant will have 100-3000 DeviceId

Table Strucutre:
 - TenantID (bigint) (i could use smallint, but I changed to bigint if i need to use Azure federation in the future)
 - DeviceID (int)
 - ReadID (bigint) (Identity)
 - UIDRead (GUID)
 - ReadDate (datetime)
 - SensorState1 (tinyint)
 - SensorState2 (tinyint)
 - SensorState3 (tinyint)
...
 - SensorState10 (tinyint)

Common WHERE´s used to read data:
-WHERE DeviceId = @X and ReadDate Between @XDate and @YDate
-WHERE DeviceId IN (X,Y,Z) AND ReadDate Between @XDate and @YDate
-WHERE TenantId = @Y and ReadDate BETWEEN @XDate and @YDate
-WHERE TenantId = @X AND DeviceID IN (X,Y,Z) AND ReadDate Between @XDate and @YDate
-WHERE TenantId = @X AND DeviceID =@Y AND ReadDate Between @XDate and @YDate

Comment: What column did you define as the key for the clustered index? ReadID looks like it should be the clustering key as it is unique, fairly narrow and ever increasing.  If it is that column (on its own) and you're still getting these long delays inserting data, then something else is definitely going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the primary key?  I assume `ReadDate`, `TenantId`, and `DeviceId` constitute a unique identifier?  If so, cluster on them, in that order, by declaring the primary key in the table definition.  Always put dates at the front of the clustered index for time-series data, because ranges will be contiguous.  (Yes, I understand each tenant reads only his own data.  The server doesn't know that, and the cache will tend to hold all the data for all tenants because (I bet) most tenants will mostly be interested in the same dates.)

Use the narrowest columns possible.  Don't use `BIGINT` now in case you'll want to federate later; when that day comes, if it comes, `ALTER TABLE` will be waiting for you.  Use `smalldatetime` unless you need seconds.  Drop `ReadId` because you already have a natural keys and it's both wasting space and a source of resource contention.  Change `UIDRead` to a normal integer and hope for the day you have over 2 billion readers.

If the resulting table is still slow to accept inserts, it's not the table's fault.  See the server.

Comment: It shouldn't be, based on what you've said.  Is the combination I mentioned not unique?  If not, what distinguishes two rows other than ReadId?  If nothing, why two rows?  If you insist on keeping it, alter the table so it's not clustering on the primary key, and cluster (hopefully uniquely) on the columns I recommended.

Comment: the conbination that you said is not unique (i could have 2 reads at same time to an deviceid)

Comment: I would keep adding columns to my primary key until I had a unique identifier or ran out of columns.  Once all columns are in the key, I'd either discard duplicates or add a column that I would increment whenever additional duplicates arrive.  I would not use an identity column to distinguish them because if they happen "at the same time" then the order of arrival really is insignificant.

Comment: No success, i tried this configurations of PK clustered index: "ReadDate,TenantId,DeviceId,ReadId"/"ReadDate,TenantId,ReadId"/"TenantId,ReadId" for all this my insert time is above 2000ms, when i put only "ReadId" as PK clustered index the insert time gets <30ms...

Comment: Can't explain that.  Something else is going on.  Two seconds to insert a single row with a handful of small columns is too long.  I still think ReadID is not your friend.  I would check with your DBA to find out what's really going on.  Not sure who that would be with Azure.

Comment: I cleaned all rows and still having this issue, It seems something in .net side of application, maybe my ORM... thanks!